# Lost Internet connection after installing Docker

Tags: windows-10, docker, docker-for-windows

I installed Docker today and after restarting my machine, I don't have an Internet connection.

I don't know what setting Docker is changing but after uninstalling Docker the problem is still there.

What can I do to fix the issue?

Comment: There is  not enough information in this question to give an answer. Please add some details, like what your network setup is. (E.g. single NIC and DHCP). Is it only internet connection which is lost or can you also no longer reach your local network?  (e.g. try pinging the IP of your local router). etc etc